# Sinngemäße Übersetzung von "venomous" und "poisonous"

Tags: english-to-german, difference

Im Englischen wird bei giftigen Tieren unter anderem zwischen "poisonous" und "venomous" unterschieden. Zur schnellen Unterscheidung gibt es den Merksatz "If you bite it and die, it is poisonous; if it bites you and you die, it is venomous."

Meine Frage ist, wie übersetzt man diese beiden Wörter am besten ins Deutsche? Standardmäßig werden beide mit "giftig" übersetzt. Bei einem Satz wie z. B. "All animals of the species xyz are poisonous" wäre die Übersetzung "Alle Tiere der Spezies xyz sind giftig". Dabei geht aber die Information verloren, auf welche Weise sie giftig sind. Außerdem kann man nicht einfach davon ausgehen, dass der Leser die Spezies kennt und es daraus ableitet.

Wie geht man hier am besten vor? Das Wort einfach mit *giftig* übersetzen? Weitere Informationen dazuschreiben oder gibt es für beide Wörter deutsche Fachbegriffe, die dies ausdrücken, aber noch immer allgemein genug sind?

Comment: Gute Frage. Erste Gedanken: Für *poisonous*, würde ich sagen, ist "giftig bei Verzehr" gebräuchlich. - Interessant ist, dass "giftig bei Berührung" sowohl *poisonous* als auch *venomous* sein kann, jenachdem, wie die Berührung vonstatten geht.

Comment: Es gibt im Deutschen dafür keinen Unterschied - schon daran erkennbar, dass es sowohl *Giftschlange* als auch *Giftpilz* und sowohl *Schlangengift* als auch *Pflanzengift* heißt.

Comment: @tofro. Genau weil es im Deutschen keine alltagssprachlich lexikalisierte Unterscheidung zwischen *v* und *p* gibt, stellte mtwde ja die Frage. Das gedankliche Konzept ist jedoch auch dem deutsch geprägten Hirne verständlich, und in gegebenem Kontext wird man auch willens und in der Lage sein, den Unterschied mit Worten auszudrücken. Also: "giftig bei Verzehr" und... tja... "giftig bei Gebissenwerden"? Ich bin sicher, der Veterinärtoxikologe oder auch der Humanmediziner hat da einen Ausdruck parat...

Comment: Bei Giften, die wirken, wenn man sie anfasst oder wenn sie sonstwie von außen auf einen einwirken, spricht man von *Kontaktgift*.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Bin nicht sicher, ob wir das Konzept wirklich unterscheiden - *giftig* heißt ganz einfach "bringt Gift in meinen Körper" - Die ursprüngliche Bedeutung *bringend* (gemeinsame Wortherkunft mit dem englischen *gift*) unterscheidet das schon nicht: Wer beißt, sticht oder ißt, ist dabei egal.

Comment: Ich wäre bei der offenbar beabsichtigten gemeinsprachlichen Verwendung nicht so besorgt, dass bei der Übersetzung von "poisonous" mit "giftig" allzu viel auf der Strecke bleibt. Zwar fällt die Fachbedeutung auseinander. Die Wörterbücher legen für die Gemeinsprache aber Oberbegrifflichkeit von "poisonous" nahe: Das OED definiert "poisonous" als "Containing, or of the nature of, poison; having the properties of a poison; venomous", MW Unabridged vermerkt in der Definition von "poisonous": "also : venomous - a poisonous spider".

Comment: Wenn man es wirklich darauf anlegte, könnte man das passive Adjektiv _giftig_ dem aktiven Partizip _vergiftend_ gegenüberstellen. Was den Verzehr angeht, gibt es auch _ungenießbar_. Ansonsten würde ich im Bedarfsfall _giftig bei Verzehr / Kontakt / Biss_ o.ä. schreiben.

Comment: @Crissov. Da stimme ich zu. Es kann ja durchaus Kontexte geben, wo man - ohne allzu medizinisch-faschsprachlich werden zu wollen - eine differenzierte Information transportieren möchte, z.B. in einem Buch mit Tipps fürs Outdoor-Leben: "Diese Schlange ist giftig, wenn sie beißt, aber sie sie ist ungiftig im Verzehr." Eine Reihe der berühmten Dschungelgifte (Pfeilspitzen) hat ja auch diese Eigenschaft: tödlich, wenn sie direkt ins Blut kommen, aber harmlos, wenn man sie verspeist.

Comment: Im englischen ist es zwar korrekt zwischen poison und venom zu unterscheiden, aber praktisch wird poison oft falsch verwendet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Irgendwie hat mich diese Frage nicht losgelassen und wie Hubert in seiner Antwort schrieb scheint es keine direkte Ein-Wort-Übersetzung zu geben. Allerdings fand ich folgende gebräuchliche Hilfskontruktion: **Aktiv/passiv giftig**

poisonous

> **passiv giftige Tiere**: Sie besitzen keinen Giftapparat; vielmehr beruht
> ihre Giftigkeit auf Substanzen, die sie mit dem Stoffwechsel bilden
> oder mit ihrer Nahrung aufnehmen. > In diese Gruppe gehören in erster
> Linie Muscheln und Fische, bei deren Verzehr es beim Menschen zu
> Magen-Darm- oder Nervenvergiftungen kommt.

venomous

> **aktiv giftige Tiere**: Sie haben die Fähigkeit, selbst Gift zu
> produzieren, das sie über Stacheln, Klauen, und Zähne auf andere
> Lebewesen übertragen können. In diese Gruppe gehören Schlangen,
> Quallen, Fische, Skorpione und Spinnen.

[Quelle](https://www.lecturio.de/lexikon/giftige-tiere)

Dementsprechend kann man schreiben

> Der Inlandtaipan ist aktiv giftig.
>
> Der Schreckliche Pfeilgiftfrosch ist passiv giftig.

**Anmerkung:**

Zu 100% glücklich bin ich mit der Antwort noch nicht und würde einen anderen Vorschlag mit einem mehr *fachlich* klingendem Ausdruck bevorzugen, wie man z.B. Karnivoren statt Fleischfresser sagen kann.

**Edit:**

Weitere Quellen

> Bei den Fischen muß unterschieden werden zwischen passiv giftigen und aktiv giftigen Tieren.
>
> 6.1. Passiv giftige Fische
>
> Von mehr als 500 Spezies weiß man, daß sie beim Verzehr zu Vergiftungen führen.

[Gift-Tiere und ihre Waffen pp 56-65, Gerhard Habermehl](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-662-00554-5_6)

> Aquatische Dermatologie: Gifttiere
>
> Gift produzierende Meerestiere applizieren ihr Gift mithilfe eines Werkzeugs zur Abwehr oder zum Beutefang (aktiv giftig) oder entfalten ihre Wirkung nach enteraler Aufnahme (passiv giftig).

[Braun-Falco's Dermatologie, Venerologie und Allergologie, Autoren Nanna Schürer, Dietrich Mebs und Andreas Montag](https://www.springermedizin.de/emedpedia/braun-falcos-dermatologie-venerologie-und-allergologie/aquatische-dermatologie-gifttiere?epediaDoi=10.1007%2F978-3-662-49546-9_47)

[SRF - PASSIV GIFTIGE TIERE](https://www.srf.ch/sendungen/netz-natur/passiv-giftige-tiere)

Comment: So richtig ausgegoren ist das aber nicht: Mir entgeht irgendwie, wie ein "aktiv giftiges Tier" "selbst Gift produzieren" könnte, das nicht aus "Substanzen, die sie mit dem Stoffwechsel bilden oder mit der Nahrung aufnehmen" besteht. Die Produktion des Giftes ist für diese Definition vollkommen irrelevant, sondern nur der evolutionäre Zweck. Ausserdem ist "aktiv" und "passiv" missverständlich: Eine Honigbiene sticht zwar "aktiv", benutzt ihr Gift aber nur, um nicht gefressen zu werden (und bezahlt selbst das noch mit dem eigenen Leben).

Comment: @tofro Stimmt, wie das Gift gebildet wird ist unwichtig für die Frage, habe es aber dennoch dringelassen, aber werde es später noch einmal editieren, damit es deutlicher wird. Das Beispiel mit der Biene kann ich nicht nachvollziehen. Aktiv/passiv bezieht sich nur auf die Art der Giftverabreichung, nicht auf den Zweck, die Folgen für das Tier oder ob es zum Angriff oder der Verteidigung genutzt wird. Aktiv: das Tier appliziert das Gift durch Stich/Biss/Stacheln/etc selbst., Passiv: Ein Angreifer nimmt das Gift durch Fressen/Berührung/etc auf

Answer (score 17):

Mir war bisher nicht gekannt, dass es Sprachen gibt, in denen man diese beiden Arten der Giftigkeit unterscheidet. Im Deutschen gibt es diesen Unterschied jedenfalls nicht, und mir wäre bisher auch nicht aufgefallen, dass es einen dringenden Bedarf gibt, das sprachlich zu trennen.

Ich zitiere mal ein paar Beispiele aus Wikipedia:

*Wenn du es beißt und daran stirbst:*

> [Giftigkeit der Kugelfische](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kugelfische#Giftigkeit): »Die Eingeweide vieler Kugelfische sind **giftig**.«

*Wenn es dich beißt und du daran stirbst:*

> [Giftschlange](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giftschlange): »Nachweislich **giftig** sind beispielsweise die kompletten Familien der Giftnattern (Elapidae) und der Vipern (Viperidae) sowie die Erdvipern (Atractaspidinae).«

*Weder selber beißen noch gebissen werden (sondern anfassen):*

> [Schrecklicher Pfeilgiftfrosch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schrecklicher_Pfeilgiftfrosch): »Der Schreckliche Pfeilgiftfrosch [...] gilt als eines der **giftigsten** Tiere und als die **giftigste** Froschart. «

Es gibt auch **Gift**pilze (giftig wenn man sie beißt) und **Gift**schlangen (giftig wenn sie dich beißen), ohne dass es dabei im Deutschen einen Unterschied beim Wort Gift gibt.

Es bleibt also festzustellen, dass im Deutschen nicht zwischen diesen beiden Arten der Giftigkeit unterschieden wird (so wie es im Japanischen ein Wort gibt (nämlich aoi - 青い), das auf deutsch sowohl blau als auch grün bedeuten kann, weil man in Japan diese beiden Farben nicht als grundsätzlich verschieden betrachtet.)

Comment: Interessant ist, daß dies sowohl auf Grün im Chinesischen und Japanischen, als auch auf Grün im Altgriechischen zutrifft. Ich suche daher schon lange nach einem biologischen Grund die Farben Grün und Blau eher als andere miteinander zu identifizieren... Im Chinesischen kann 青 zudem noch schwarz bedeuten und auch Aristoteles stellt eine Verbindung zwischen Schwarz und Grün her!

Comment: Das Japanische kennt allerdings auch *midori* für *grün*. Aoi wird als Überbegriff gesehen, d.h. alles, was midori ist, ist auch aoi, aber nicht alles was aoi ist, ist midori.

Comment: @Jan: Stimmt. Mir wäre auch noch eingefallen die beiden russischen Wörter für zwei verschiedene Arten von Blau zu erwähnen (nämlich синий *(siniy)* = kräftiges blau und голубой *(goluboy)* = blasses blau), und auch an das chinesische Wort 青, das sowohl grün als auch blau als auch schwarz bedeuten kann habe ich gedacht, aber das hätte alles den Rahmen der Antwort gesprengt,

Comment: @Ludi: grün und blau (und schwarz) sind "kalte", "dunkle" Farben, 赤 "rot/orange" ... sind "warme", "helle" Farben. Wenn man Farben einteilen will, ist das die einfachste Einteilung, und jede Sprache hat "ursprüngliche" Wörter für solche Farbeinteilung in unterschiedlicher Zahl. Wörter für Farbdifferenzierung (緑 *midori* "Blattgrün, grün", or deutsch *orange* etc.) kommen später dazu, und werden von anderen Worten abgeleitet.

Comment: @dirkt  vielen Dank. Dies klingt sehr plausibel. Andererseits habe ich keine Begriffe gefunden, die zum Beispiel Rot und Gelb in einen Topf würfen. Daß orange nicht fundamental ist, erscheint mir logisch. Vielleicht sollte ich genau das hinterfragen! Zu dem goluboi (ich spreche kein Russisch) gibt es bei Jurij Lotman eine interessante Passage. Wenn ich mich recht erinnere, erklärt er, im Altrussischen sei goluboi nicht für den Himmel verwandt worden. Sehr oft sei dieser durch die Grundfarbe von Ikonen beschrieben worden. Ich werde das noch nachtragen

Comment: @Ludi: Es gibt verschiedene Theorien zur Farbentwicklung, nach [Berlin/Kay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distinction_of_blue_and_green_in_various_languages) wird (blasses?) Gelb oft als Variante von Grün gesehen. Im Japanischen sieht man auch deutlich, dass 黄色い *kiiroi* "lehmfarben, gelb" und 茶色い *chairoi* "teefarben, braun" später entstanden sind, und ein zusätzliches 色 "Farbe" im Wort haben - genauso wie das "offizielle" deutsche Adjektiv von Orange "orangenfarben" ist. Siehe auch https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_relativity_and_the_color_naming_debate

Comment: Englisch/deutsch: Sky/heaven vs. Himmel.

Answer (score 2):

Der Unterschied zwischen den Wörtern *poisonous* und *venomous* liegt in den verschiedenen Wurzeln, die mit dem Suffix [-ous](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ous) adjektiviert werden.

[poison](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/poison)

> a substance with an inherent property that tends to destroy life or impair health
>
> [eine Substanz mit einer inhärenten Eigenschaft, die dazu tendiert, Leben zu zerstören oder die Gesundheit zu beeinträchtigen]

[venom](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/venom)

> the poisonous fluid that some animals, as certain snakes and spiders, secrete and introduce into the bodies of their victims by biting, stinging, etc.
>
> [ die giftige Flüssigkeit, die einige Tiere wie bestimmte Schlangen und Spinnen absondern und in den Körper ihrer Opfer durch Beißen oder Stechen usw. einbringen]

Da ich keine englischer Muttersprachler bin, fällt es mir schwer, die Qualität dieser Definitionen zu beurteilen. Aber nehmen wir an, sie sind zutreffend.

Dann entspricht *poisonous* der allgemeinen Bedeutung des deutschen Wortes *giftig*.

Eine Entsprechung des Wortes *venomous* müsste aussagen, dass **ein Tier** über Gift verfügt, das es **durch Biss oder Stich etc.** aktiv in den Körper des Opfers einbringen kann.

Die Information, dass es sich um ein Tier handelt, ist schon im Substantiv enthalten. Der Rest könnte etwa durch **giftinjizierend** übersetzt werden.

Notwendig scheint mir diese Unterscheidung nicht. Wir wissen, dass man sich von giftigen Tieren besser fernhält, ob sie nun beißen oder nicht. Sofern zusätzliche Informationen im Kontext interessant sind, müssen sie auch nicht zwingend in einem einzigen Wort ausgedrückt werden.

Darüber hinaus stellt sich mir die Frage, wie bedeutsam dieser Unterschied im Englischen tatsächlich ist und ob englische Muttersprachler da im alltäglichen Sprachgebrauch wirklich streng unterscheiden. Der Merksatz deutet darauf hin, dass das wohl häufig nicht der Fall ist. Möglicherweise ist die Bekanntheit dieses Wortpaares ja nur der im Internet recht umtriebigen *Sprachpolizei* zu verdanken.

Answer (score 2):

Letzten Endes liegt der Unterschied bei Giften doch darin, wie es aufgenommen wird bzw. bei welcher Aufnahmeart ein Vergiftungseffekt eintritt, und dafür gibt es mindestens 4 Abstufungen:

1. Aufnahme durch die Haut - hier spricht man im Deutschen ausdrücklich von "Kontaktgift" (ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob Aufnahme durch Schleimhäute hierzu zählt oder als eigene Untergruppe gezählt werden müste)
2. Aufnahme durch Einatmen - hier würde man von Giftgas oder giftigen Dämpfen reden, was sich allerdings eher auf den Aggregatzustand des Giftes zum jeweiligen Zeitpunkt und nicht auf die Substanz an sich bezieht. Letztere wäre auch einfach "Gift".
3. Aufnahme durch den Verdauungstrakt - das, was in der Frage als poison(ous) und "when you eat it" bezeichnet ist.
4. Aufnahme in die Blutbahn - typischerweise durch Biss oder Stich. Allerdings ist es auch gefährlich, dieses Gift zu berühren, wenn man eine offene Wunde hat.

Englisch macht hier eine Unterscheidung zwischen 3 (Poison) und 4 (Venom), Deutsch nicht. Auch 1 hat im Deutschen kein separates Wort, sondern nur ein Präfix. Daher würde ich den letzten Absatz aus der Frage

> Wie geht man hier am besten vor? Das Wort einfach mit giftig übersetzen?

mit "grundsätzlich ja" beantworten und

> Weitere Informationen dazuschreiben

mit "nur, falls andernfalls Mehrdeutigkeit besteht".